# How to set UIStackView to take 50% height of the parent container? Running into bizarre issues

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiview, uistoryboard

I am making a custom keyboard. I have a storyboard that contains a viewController, in which I put in a horizontal stack view controller, with three buttons. if I set the UIStack view (by ctrl drag + click to the view) to equal Height, equal Width, and center horizontally in container, and then click on the multiplier for height, and set it to the 0.5, things get weird.

Rather than take 50% of the space the default keyboard height is, it weirdly shrinks the entire view to the height of the stack, which is the height of the text of the buttons... if I set it smaller and smaller, e.g. 0.05 the keyboard view grows, taking up almost the entire screen, but the height remains the same for stack view.

All I want to do is take the stackview, and set it's height to be 50% of the view.

[image]

the grey is the button height, the red is the viewBackground. looks good in storyboard, but when running with 1 height:
[image]

with 0.05 height (ignore all other text aside for first row of qwert..):
[image]

Comment: to elaborate, in the storyboard, if I just change height to match the view, it looks right. it takes up 100% (without changing multiplier). if I run it, the height shrinks to the exact height of the UIStackView which is like 20-30 pixels rather than the default keyboard height. if I don't do this height change, the view height is the height it should be...

Comment: You didn't list a vertical position constraint for the stack view.  Is there one?

Comment: which way? I mean if I literally just only change to match height, and adjust multiplier by 0.5 it still acts funny. but if I add constraints (in bottom right) set to 0 for left, top, right, then match height, width, and center horizontally and vertically, and then adjust the multiplier for the vertical constraint to 0.5 same issue as above, very tiny view area overall :(

Comment: so if it's set to 1, the view is the height of the UIStackView. if I set the stack multiplier to 0.5, view size doubles, stack height stays the same, 0.25 quadruples height but stack height stays the same (taking a quarter of view size), and so forth

Comment: Thats weird.  Try using a manual multiple.  make the stack view a constant height like 100.  Drag an outlet for the height constraint into your viewController.  In viewDidLayoutSubviews set your hegihtConstraint.constant = 0.5 * view.bounds.size.height.

Comment: I did that, and now it takes up about 90-95% of the height, but at least the height of the stack is changing so that's good.

Comment: actually to specify, it takes 90-95% of the height of the keyboard height, which is roughly 1/3 of the screen >_>

Comment: log the frame of both he view and the stack view in in viewDidLayoutSubviews so you can see how/when its changing.  Also use the view debugger and see if you can spot anything thats off.  Something strange is going on.

Comment: so I found a value that works for 4 rows, which is 0.082 * height, and I tried it with both an iphone 7 plus and iphone 6s and seems to be working. I really don't like it though, it seems very hacky. can this be because this is a custom keyboard extension that has its own storyboard? in fact if I just try to log anything with print("Hello") nothing is showing up in console in the viewDidLoad()

Comment: alright this is very strange. print("lol") works if it's in the main viewController. in the extension viewController, let's call it p, everything in viewDidLoad is definitely working (height adjustments, changing to uppercase, etc), but printing is not printing to the terminal from that controller. and of course height is all wonky

Comment: I just tried this with a brand new project, added new target -> added new storyboard -> added stack with buttons, set their height to that of view, and if it's set to multiplier 1 it still shows up as a really small overall view where the height of the buttons is about 30 pixels and shrinks the keyboard expected height